# How To: Separate Contacts in Android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, contacts, android-contacts

**Problem**

Adding technician, electrician, plumber phone numbers in Android contacts is causing confusion.

1. Same name as my friend or a family member. I always mistakenly call the wrong person.
2. These contacts show in WhatsApp, Telegram and other apps. Facebook Instagram even suggest me to add them as friends.

**Observations**

I have observed that there are separate accounts in my contacts (such as BBC, Telegram, etc).

**Requirements**

Add a contact name - just the name without prefix electrician, plumber etc.

Eg. John Plumber
Eg. Sales GM Tony

Can I leverage accounts concept in Contacts so that these persons will be part of contacts but not mix with my personal persons.

Contacts should be available only in android and should not be shared to WhatsApp or other apps.

I am an ionic developer and wanted to know if the above can be achieved with hybrid apps + native plugins?

Answer (score 0):

your "requirements" don't really make sense, "available only in Android", means those contacts will be part of the Contacts DB and therefore available to other apps, such as Whatsapp - which will be able to query them.

Android uses a central DB for contacts shared by all apps - system apps, google apps, and all others.

So I guess the short answer would be - that's not possible in Android.